# Настройка очереди в laravel

Tags: laravel, php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить очереди в `laravel`? Если несложно краткую инструкцию...

Дело в том, что сейчас очереди выполняются сразу же, без каких либо задержек, а мне нужно выполнение через три/пять минут.

Answer (score 1):

Очереди для того и созданы что бы выполнятся по очереди и мгновенно если очередь не пустая.

Единственный способ в этом случае, внутри задачи, в самом начале поставить sleep(количество секунд).

Задача выполнится с задержкой и пока она работает, следующая не запустится.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо рассказано про то, как работать с очередями [тут](https://laracasts.com/lessons/beanstalkd-queues-with-laravel). Если из других источников, то [вот](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4)

Answer (score 0):

Отсюда для 5.2: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#delayed-jobs

> you may wish to queue a job that sends a customer a reminder e-mail 15 minutes after sign-up. You may accomplish this using the delay method on your job class, which is provided by the Illuminate\Bus\Queueable trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\SendReminderEmail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send a reminder e-mail to a given user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendReminderEmail(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->delay(60);
```